# javascript, how to convert text from response of post request on backend?

Tags: javascript, fetch

this is response from backend (swagger)
[image: swagger response]

but when I open network tab in browser, response is weird:
[image: browser response]

when I look on postman they are doing response.text(), and result is okay:
[image]

how can I achieve that with javascript (using React)?

I tried decoding, encoding, transform to base 64 but could not achieve postman and swagger results.

Answer (score 0):

@borna you confused with response, API send you a file which postman or swagger can easily understand,

no need to convert file content, its a PDF file you just need to download it.
try following code

```
const handleDownload = () => {
const link = document.createElement("a");
link.target = "_blank";
link.download = "YOUR_FILE_NAME"
axios
  .get(url, {
    responseType: "blob",
  })
  .then((res) => {
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(
      new Blob([res.data], { type: "pdf" })
    );
    link.click();
  });
```

};